# Modularized version of a simple Shiny app produces an error

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making my first attempt to modularize a very simple app using Shiny modules. This is a modular version of the same app in the accepted answer to my question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74840494/2990040). I have one module to allow the user to enter a name and add it to a list of names (stored in a character vector) and a second module to display the updated contents of the vector.

The result I expected was this: (the same output as my non-modular version)
`[1] "Mary"  "Steve"`

But what I got was unexpected in 2 ways: At app startup, I get `Error: sink stack is full`. Then as I add two names to the list, the output looks like this:

```
[[1]]
reactiveVal:
[1] "structure(function (x) , {,     if (missing(x)) {,         rv$get(),     },     else {,         force(x),         rv$set(x),     }, }, class = c(\"reactiveVal\", \"reactive\", \"function\"), label = \"nameList\", .impl = <environment>)"
[2] "Mary"
[3] "Steve"

[[2]]
[1] "Mary"

[[3]]
[1] "Steve"
```

My app.R code:

```
library(shiny)

newNameUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("name"), "Name:"),
    actionButton(ns("btnSave"), "Save")
  )
}

listNamesUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    h5("Output:"),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

newNameServer <- function(id, nameList) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$btnSave, {
      nameList(append(nameList(), input$name))
    })
    return(nameList)
  })
}

listNamesServer <- function(id, nameList) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$out <- renderPrint(nameList())
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    newNameUI("newName")),
  fluidRow(
    listNamesUI("listNames"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  nameList <- reactiveVal()
  
  nameList(newNameServer("newName", nameList))
  
  listNamesServer("listNames", nameList)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a `reactiveVal` there is no need to return `nameList` in your `newNameServer`. `nameList` gets updated when you do `nameList(append(nameList(), input$name))`.

But the main issue is your attempt to update  `nameList` in the main server using `nameList(newNameServer("newName", nameList))`. To make your app work get rid of this construction and simply do `newNameServer("newName", nameList)`.

```
library(shiny)

newNameUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("name"), "Name:"),
    actionButton(ns("btnSave"), "Save")
  )
}

listNamesUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    h5("Output:"),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

newNameServer <- function(id, nameList) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$btnSave, {
      nameList(append(nameList(), input$name))
    })
  })
}

listNamesServer <- function(id, nameList) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$out <- renderPrint(nameList())
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    newNameUI("newName")),
  fluidRow(
    listNamesUI("listNames"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  nameList <- reactiveVal()
  
  newNameServer("newName", nameList)
  
  listNamesServer("listNames", nameList)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]